# whats wrong with this function in this file : vendor\illuminate\events\Dispatcher.php. the vscode editor is throwing an error, i dont know how to sol

Tags: php, slim, symfony-eventdispatcher

I am trying to run a slim project, and its throwing an error from the Dispatcher file. the error is on this function:  public function getListeners($eventName)
{
$listeners = $this->listeners[$eventName] ?? [];

```
    $listeners = array_merge(
        $listeners,
        $this->wildcardsCache[$eventName] ?? $this->getWildcardListeners($eventName)
    );

    return class_exists($eventName, false)
                ? $this->addInterfaceListeners($eventName, $listeners)
                : $listeners;
}
```

any suggestion on how to correct this error?

Comment: And _what_ error exactly is thrown? What does it say?

Comment: I could imagine, just as an example, that the `??` is pointed out as syntax error due to your php version not matching the requirements.

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fypms\vendor\illuminate\events\Dispatcher.php on line 291" that is the error am getting when i try to run the project

Comment: And what line is that, _exactly_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your PHP version in VS code is set wrongly. E.g. PHP5.6 when the actual code runs on a higher version.

The null coalescing operator was added in PHP 7.